# Early 80’s to 2000’s kids show with kids in a space convertible with someone in a bear costume

Tags: story-identification, tv

It was a kids show and the one scene I remember is that there were kids in space with a guy in an animal costume (I believe a bear) and they were on a spaceship that was, I guess, convertible. That's really all I can remember. Hopefully someone knows it.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where did you see this?  Was it live-action or animated?

Comment: Was the guy in the animal costume supposed to visibly be in a costume, or was it bad special effects?

Comment: I advise visiting https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question, which has some questions that may prompt more detail that you can [edit] into your question.

Comment: Actually, a question I probably should have asked, are you saying that the spaceship could change shape? That it could cruise around with the top down like a "convertible" car? :-P I was assuming the latter.

Comment: I won't be happy until I see a bear, in a convertible, in space.

Answer (score 2):

Astro Farm, potentially? The spaceship that features prominently in the opening looks rather like a convertible, and it is a kid's show. Though the animal in the spaceship is a dog rather than someone in a costume.

Comment: Needs more bear.

Answer (score 1):

Might it be *[They Came from Outer Space](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0098927/)*?

> Two teenage aliens, Abe and Bo, travel the United States in a red sports car in an effort to pick up chicks and learn more about life on Earth. They are pursued by a pair of bumbling U.S. Government soldiers who would like to capture Abe and Bo for study.

[image: Front cover of the They Came from Outer Space boxed set]

I have not found reference to a bear costume, but it is a space convertible. Another potentially non-matching point is that it is not a kid's show, and [one episode](https://femalevillains.fandom.com/wiki/User_blog:Doalfe/Molly_Meecham_(They_Came_From_Outer_Space)) even included a bit where a woman is undressed on stage by their powers, and revealed in her underwear.

Found with a search for `1980s tv show space convertible`

### First episode